# Flutter json_serializable 5.0.0 is not working along with auto_route

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, jsonserializer

I'm getting below error after upgrading the json_serializable lib from 4.1.4 to 5.0.0

can anyone please explain what is wrong with the versions I'm using?

Because no versions of auto_route_generator match >2.1.0 <3.0.0 and auto_route_generator 2.1.0 depends on analyzer >=0.40.0 <2.0.0, auto_route_generator ^2.1.0 requires analyzer >=0.40.0 <2.0.0.
And because json_serializable >=5.0.0 depends on analyzer ^2.0.0, auto_route_generator ^2.1.0 is incompatible with json_serializable >=5.0.0.
So, because carer_connect depends on both json_serializable ^5.0.0 and auto_route_generator ^2.1.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because carer_connect depends on both json_serializable ^5.0.0 and auto_route_generator ^2.1.0, version solving failed.)

[image]

This is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```
name: demo
description: demo

publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^4.0.0
  auto_route: ^2.2.0
  json_serializable: ^5.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  build_runner:
  auto_route_generator: ^2.1.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/config/
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @cubanGuy I have added a solution below. please check if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

this step work with me

### 1 - add dependencies in pubspec.yaml file

```
  dio: ^4.0.0
  json_serializable: ^4.1.4
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
```

### 2- run this command to reset version

```
dart pub upgrade --null-safety
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
json_serializable: any
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: using `any` is not a good practice, especially in production.

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the `auto_route_generator` depends on `json_serializable: ^4.1.4` internally inside that package, but you are using `json_serializable` externally and the version used in both cases doesn't match, thus the error,

One solution for this is you can use both versions and mention one version inside `dependencies:` and another inside `dependency_overrides:` like this:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  json_serializable: ^5.0.0
  ...

dependency_overrides:
  ...
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
  json_serializable: ^4.1.4
  ...
```

And the problem should be solved. If any further complication arises you can always check which version is used inside the package's internal `pubspec.yaml` and add them as `dependency_overrides:` in your code.